# Is $xy$ certainly not a square in $\mathbb Z_n$ if $x$ is a square and $y$ is not?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic, cryptography

If $x$ is a square of any element in $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ but $y$ is *not* a square of any element in $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ then can we conclusively say that $xy$ is *not* a square of any element in $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$?

I'm afraid that something weird might happen modulo $n$. Say, $x = g^2 \bmod n$ and $xy = h^2 \bmod n$ where $g, h \in \mathbb Z_n$. Then how exactly to draw a contradiction from here?

(I was stuck on this issue while thinking about the zero-knowledge proof strategy for quadratic residue.)

Comment: It can happen that $x$ and $xy$ are squares but $y$ is not: if $n=8$, $x=4=2^2$, and $y=2$, then $xy=0$ which is a square.

Comment: @KReiser Very interesting, thanks. I think the $x$ needs be from $\mathbb Z^\times$ instead for us to be able to make the conclusion (?).

Comment: Yes, exactly - if $x$ is a unit, then $g$ is too, so $xy=h^2$ implies $y=(h/g)^2$.

Comment: @KReiser Awesome. Thank you so much! Now that I re-checked, the articles on ZK proofs for QR do mention this intricacy. For example, here: https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall07/cos433/lec15.pdf.

Comment: it may be part of their assumption of algebraic background in the princeton course

Comment: http://math.fau.edu/yiu/NT2017Spring/NT2017SpringChapters8to9.pdf